# ValueAnimator мгновенно заканчивается

Tags: java, android, animator

Написал вот такой тестовый код:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100).setDuration(10000);
        valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                Log.i("PRIVET", "1");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                Log.i("PRIVET", "2");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                Log.i("PRIVET", "3");
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                Log.i("PRIVET", "4");
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Запускаю приложение и через мгновение вижу такой вывод:

```
I/PRIVET: 1
I/PRIVET: 2
```

, хотя аниматор должен был закончиться только через десять секунд.

С чем это может быть связано?

---

Протестировал на эмуляторе - там всё работает нормально. Значит, проблема в моём телефоне. В опциях разработчика анимация включена. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте подключить конкретный View и указать свойство.

Comment: @Style-7 скопировал код [отсюда](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/viewanimator), он работает. Надо разбираться, почему.